# i have an if statement but i have a problem

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, pagination

So I have a problem, it's hard to explain but can be described as follows:

[this is ouput if i paginate 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0jQ8.png)

The image above, I paginate 10, can be seen from the following code:

```
$list = Anime::where('status', 1)->paginate(10);
```

[output-2 paginate 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR98H.png)

and if the image above, I paginate 5, it can be seen from the following code:

```
$list = Anime::where('status', 1)->paginate(5);
```

The following code image is displayed (blade file):

```html
<div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
 @if ($creator[$i]->profile_photo_path)
  @php
  $isi = $creator[$i]->profile_photo_path;
 @endphp
  <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src='{{ asset("storage/$isi") }}' alt="">
 @elseif ($creator[$i]->profile_photo_path == null || !$creator[$i]->profile_photo_path)
  <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="{{ asset('storage/profile-photos/default.svg') }}"     alt="">
 @endif
</div>
```

The following is the full content of the blade file:

```html
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Public List Anime') }}
        </h2>
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <div class="-my-2 overflow-x-hidden sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                    <div class="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        <div class="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
                            <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                                <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col" class="hidden md:inline-block px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                            Username
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                            Title
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                            Genre
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                                            Rating
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="relative px-6 py-3">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                                    @foreach ($list as $i => $l)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="hidden md:inline-block px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                            <div class="flex items-center">
                                                <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                                                    @if ($creator[$i]->profile_photo_path)
                                                    @php
                                                    $isi = $creator[$i]->profile_photo_path;
                                                    @endphp
                                                    <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src='{{ asset("storage/$isi") }}' alt="">
                                                    @elseif ($creator[$i]->profile_photo_path == null || !$creator[$i]->profile_photo_path)
                                                    <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="{{ asset('storage/profile-photos/default.svg') }}" alt="">
                                                    @endif
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ml-4">
                                                    <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                                                        {{ Illuminate\Support\Str::of($l->email)->title() }}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-900">{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::of($l->title)->title() }}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                            <span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-green-100 text-green-800">
                                                @php $g = explode(',', $l->genre) @endphp
                                                {{ Illuminate\Support\Str::of($g[0])->title() }}
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                                            
                                            {{ $l->score }} <i class="fal fa-stars"></i>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                                            <a href="{{ route('show', $l->id) }}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Detail</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span>
                {{ $list->links() }}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the controller method index:

```php
public function index()
    {
        $list = Anime::where('status', 1)->paginate(5);

        $creator = Anime::join('users', 'users.email', '=', 'animes.email')
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->get('users.profile_photo_path');

        return view('anime.publicList', compact('list', 'creator'));
    }
```

**The problem is if I paginate it to 5 then when on the 2nd page the user image turns into an admin image (unlike the first image which paginated 10)**

Comment: Are both admin image and user image loading from `users.profile_photo_path`? Or is anyone of those the default image?

Comment: the admin image is from users.profile_photo_path, but the user img is from default image bcuz the user not set the img

Comment: Could be a cache issue. What happens when you reset cache? (hold Ctrl and reload) Or if you are using chrome, in the network tab of inspect elements, theres disable cache. Worth giving it a try I think

Answer (score -1):

#Solved in the following manner :

i try to change variabel $creator to have paginate ( equates to the $ anime variable )

so I changed to something like the following :

```
$creator = Anime::join('users', 'users.email', '=', 'animes.email')
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->select('users.*')
    ->paginate(5);
```